# How to use global variables in pseudo code?

Tags: language-agnostic, global-variables, pseudocode

I have some pseudo, where I have to use global variables. Now I can't find any documentation about how to "tag" them. Even if pseudo is pseudo, there are some rules, which I like to respect.

Here's a small example:

```
FUNCTION calculation(a,b) 
BEGIN
v = b * a
c = b / a
IF (v mod c == 0) THEN
    return v
ELSE 
    return c
END IF
END
```

Now `v` is a global variable and `a, b, c` are local ones. There is no way to spot this scenario immediately. What's the right way to mark `v` as a global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't really any rules as such, just various loose conventions. Since you've gone for a somewhat "Pascal" flavour of pseudo code then you could just adapt Pascal syntax for your example:

```pascal
VAR
  v    { global variable }

FUNCTION calculation(a,b) 
  VAR
    c  { local variable }
  BEGIN
    v = b * a
    c = b / a
    IF (v mod c == 0) THEN
      return v
    ELSE 
      return c
    END IF
  END
```